# Modal not shown on safari

Tags: jquery, html, safari

I have created a modal that is shown when you click on an element. It works great in most browsers, but not in Safari. I'm not sure why.
I already tried replacing addClass by toggleClass.

Any idea what could cause this?

My code;

Javascript:

```
 // SHOW popup modal
jQuery(".trigger_popup").on('click', function(){
    var popupTarget = jQuery(this).attr('data-target');
    jQuery('.modal_popup').addClass('visible');
    jQuery('.popup-text.' + popupTarget).addClass('visible');

});
```

Element:

```
<span class="trigger_popup infoLable" data-target="bodem"><?php echo $wizardlang_bottomres ?></span>
```

Thanks!!

Modal:

```
 <div class="popup-text bodem">
        <h2><?php echo $wizardlang_bottomres ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $wizardlang_resultpopup_bottom ?></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparantly it was just an issue with the modal css itself. I used another modal example and now its working.